# Sending Base64 PDF as email in symfony 2.8>

Tags: php, symfony1, swiftmailer, jspdf

I have a PDF generated by jsPDF as a blob/base64 string, and I want to sent it to recipients through swiftmail without having to decode the string, create a PDF file and finnally attach it to the Mail.

My question is, Is their a way of attaching Bas64 to swiftmail and if it is possible will the recipient be able to see the file as a PDf using PDF viewers.

Comment: The answer of Gollm worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to attach a file to a SwiftMail you need to provide the content to `Swift_Attachment::setBody()` and it can NOT be base_64 (i already tried with images) or create the actual file in the filesystem and use `Swift_Attachment::fromPath()` so you will HAVE to decode you pdf anyways.

SwiftMailer doc: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-existing-files

Answer (score 1):

You **have** to decode the string

```
$mail->attach(new \Swift_Attachment(base64_decode($pdfBase64String), 'Pdf.pdf', 'application/pdf'));
```

Comment: This was very helpfull!!